# Simultaneous clicking of the left and right mouse buttons using RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to catch the event simultaneously pressing the left and right mouse buttons with **RxJS**. More precisely, you need to catch the mouseup event with the right and left mouse buttons with a maximum difference of 300 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create two streams, one for left and one for right clicks
2. map both of these the `Date.now()`
3. Then you want to `combineLatest` the two streams
4. Finally `filter` the values which are more than 300ms apart

Answer (score 0):

On the advice of [Tom Cumming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8318454/tom-cumming)

```
import { fromEvent, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators'
const upLeft$ = fromEvent(document, 'mouseup').pipe(filter((e) => e.which === 1), map(()=>Date.now()))
const upRight$ = fromEvent(document, 'mouseup').pipe(filter((e) => e.which === 3), map(()=>Date.now()))

const combined$ = combineLatest(upLeft$ , upRight$).pipe(filter((e)=> (e[1]-e[0])<=300 && (e[1]-e[0])>0), map((e)=> (e[1]-e[0])));

combined$.subscribe(() => {
console.log("It work!!!")
});
```

Comment: you might want `Math.abs(e[1] - e[0]) <= 300`